# @PathVariable validation gives 500 instead of 400

Tags: spring, spring-validator

In the Spring Framework validating the request respond with error 400 (Bad Request), specially when validating the request body and the request fields decorated with the
`javax.validation.constraints.*` annotations (which specified in JSR 303).

For make it more clear lets go through the example:

I have decorated the fields of the class `ContactDetails` with `@Email` and `@NotEmpty` constraints

```
class ContactDetails {
    @Email
    String email;

    @NotEmpty
    String message;
}
```

In the controller I used `@Valid` annotation to make Spring Validator validate the http request body.

```
@RestController
class NotificationController {
    @PostMapping("/sendNotification")
    public String sendNotification(@Valid @RequestBody ContactDetails contactDetails) {
        ... 
    }
}
```

If the validation fails, it will trigger a `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. By default, Spring will translate this exception to a HTTP status 400 (Bad Request).

But for validating the request params or path variables based on Spring documentations I will decorate the controller class with `@Validated` and just using `javax.validation.constraints.*` annotations on the parameters and I expect the same result same as validating the request body.

```
@Validated
@RestController
class NotificationController {
    @GetMapping("/getContactDetailsByEmail/{email}")
    public ContactDetails findContactDetails(@Email String email) {
        ... 
    }
}
```

In contrast to request body validation a failed validation will trigger a ***ConstraintViolationException*** instead of a ***MethodArgumentNotValidException***. Spring does not register a default exception handler for this exception, so it will by default cause a response with HTTP status 500 (Internal Server Error).

I expected to get error 400 for this scenario and I do not know if I missed any thing in my code?
That would be great if any body can help me with this scenario why Spring has different approaches for validating the parameters.

Comment: Because one is done with AOP (the path variable) and the other is build into the web handling. The latter will give you a 400, the other one a 500, unless you write an exceptionhandler to return a 400. They are different mechanism for a different purpose and hence different errors (the AOP one is more generic and generally intended for the service layer).

Answer (score 5):

You can create the answer you want by using the fields in the ConstraintViolationException with the following method;

```
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handlePathVariableError(final ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);

        final List<SisSubError> subErrors = new ArrayList<>();
        exception.getConstraintViolations().forEach(constraintViolation -> subErrors.add(generateSubError(constraintViolation)));

        final SisError error = generateErrorWithSubErrors(VALIDATION_ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, subErrors);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In the first case - with argument annotated with `@RequestBody` - Spring uses `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` to validate it and [throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException` if validation fails](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java#L126), which is handled later by [`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java#L133) or [`DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java#L202) by translating it into 400 BAD REQUEST http response code.

In the second case Spring is using AOP for method validation with `MethodValidationInterceptor` class, [which throws `ConstraintViolationException` if validation fails](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationInterceptor.java#L131).
But, unlike the first case, **Spring doesn't provide a default exception handler for `ConstraintViolationException`**, so it's translated into 500 http response code.
That's why developers should consider creating their own exception handlers for this kind of method-level validation.